# Add extension method to NullObject

Tags: grails, groovy, extension-methods

## Description

I have an extension method added to `Number`, that lets me do easy formatting to danish monetary format, e.g.:

```
assert new BigDecimal('10000.55').toBelob() == '10.000,55'
assert new BigDecimal('0').toBelob() == '0,00'
```

However, I need to *safe navigate* most places, e.g.:

```
someNumber?.toBelob()
```

## Question

Since all `null` literals in Groovy are wrapped in a `NullObject`, would it be completely insane to add the extension method to Groovy's `NullObject` as well?

I could then skip the safe navigation, e.g.:

```
BigDecimal someNumber = null
...
assert someNumber.toBelob() == '0,00'
```

Comment: Have you tried it and does it work and you are unsure if this is a good idea or are you asking if you should try it?  If 2 then maybe try 1?

Comment: Yes, this is what the language libraries do to handle the case of null object expression, if you want a non-null return value. You can have a look at DefaultGroovyMethods or PluginDefaultGroovyMethods for examples.  If you just want to return null, then I'd stick with safe navigation.

Comment: @cfrick yes it works, the question is *only* weather it's a good idea or there is complications.

Comment: every idea is good if used with care. In your case I think it's legit to extend `NullObject` as it should conflict with existing stuff

Comment: "Since all `null` literals in Groovy are wrapped in a `NullObject`...".  Be aware that not all `null` values are `null` literals.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I'm not sure I get that, can you calrify?